# Twitting URLs with # in them and getting their count

Tags: url, twitter, count, share, tweets

The goal here is to be able to "tweet" a link of the format
www.example.com/page.aspx#1, and get the number of "tweets" for that link... Basically, what the out-of-the-box Twitter button does for any normal link.

Reason for this is because the page displays different content based on the ID after the #, so there is a need to count which specific item was "tweeted" and how many times.

I tried passing that URL to the Twitter service  to get the count (http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=), but the JSON object I get back only has
    `{"count":0,"url":"www.example.com/page.aspx/"}`.

The link for the Twitter button looks like this (done in JavaScript)

```
var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+encodeURIComponent(twtUrl)+'&counturl='+encodeURIComponent(twtUrl);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter actually re-interrupts all URL's with their own custom `t.co` wrapper. This is good news for your use case. You can use these unique t.co links with the counter API.

If you include the attribute `&include_entities=1` to the end of some Twitter REST API calls you get back expanded info including the URL's in the tweets. You will see the original URL as well as the shortened URL version. Pass the shortened URL version into the counter API.